# Importing tensorflow_datasets

Tags: installation, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to import tensorflow_datasets to load a data set, but I found that I should install tensorflow_datasets using either pip or conda. I installed it twice using both methods. But tensorflow_datasets do not still work in jupyter notebook. In the last attempt I got the following error:
`ImportError: cannot import name 'kwarg_only' from 'tensorflow.python.util.tf_export'`

Plus
`Failed to import TensorFlow. Please note that TensorFlow is not installed by default when you install TensorFlow Datasets. This is so that users can decide whether to install the GPU-enabled TensorFlow package. To use TensorFlow Datasets, please install the most recent version of TensorFlow, by following instructions at https://tensorflow.org/install.`

While I have TensorFlow installed. I searched the net but none of the solutions solved the problem. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a separate environment and then install tensorflow and tensorflow_datasets using `pip install tensorflow==2.0.0` and `pip install tensorflow_datasets==2.1.0`. Its works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install by `pip install tensorflow-datasets==4.4.0` using either conda prompt or on jupiter notebook is ok